# Azure Cache Monitoring Tool

Tags: caching, azure, monitoring, performancecounter, performance

Hoping some could direct me to a tool that i can use to monitor azure caching performance.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618005.aspx) above describes how the Azure management portal presents "Current Size", "Peak Size(this month/last year)". But I'm after more detailed information.

I'm currently investigating Cerebrata's [Windows Azure Powershell Cmdlets](http://cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets/Details.aspx?t1=0&t2=4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the MSDN article states, you'll need to work through the portal to create and monitor your cache. There are currently no API calls for monitoring a cache, which also means there are no Powershell cmdlets (which are built upon the various REST API's).

Comment: Thanks David. Can you make reference to the MSDN article? So I presume the Azure management portal doesnt use the Cmdlets? You suggest using the portal to manage cache usage but all it really tells me is the current size? Can you confirm this is the only method to monitor cache? and if so is there any further developments in the azure API to retrieve cache info. Thanks,

Comment: I'm talking about the article you referenced in MDSN, in your question. Regarding Windows Azure Powershell cmdlets: They're just Powershell extensions that, under the hood, make calls to the Windows Azure Management API, or Storage API, Service Bus API, and ACS API. Right now, there's no API defined for cache, so there are no cmdlets that can be written. I can't talk about any possible future developments - sorry!

Comment: This is my understanding as well David, but I'm confused by this line "Once you start using your deployed application, you’ll notice a rich set of metrics being automatically generated [...] to the number of times your cache gets called." in this article about appfabric cache applications here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2011/06/20/introducing-windows-azure-appfabric-applications.aspx